# How to perform Binary search in insertion sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, binary-search, insertion-sort

I am a beginner in java i have been trying to perform insertion sort and then binary search .I have performed insertion sort with random different values and them i have to perform binary search. I am able to do the binary search technique separately but how is it possible to perform insertion sort with specific values and then perform binary search with those same values used in insertion sort ?

Insertion Sort:

```
enter code here
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project  
Properties.


* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package insertsort;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
*
* @author Sriram
*/

public class InsertSort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int A[] = new int[1000];
populateArray(A);
System.out.println("Before Sorting: ");
printArray(A);
// sort the array
insertSort(A);
System.out.println("\nAfter Sorting: ");
printArray(A);
}

/**
 * This method will sort the integer array using insertion sort algorithm
 * 
 * @param arr
 */
private static void insertSort(int[] arr) {
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int valueToSort = arr[i];
        int j = i;
        while (j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > valueToSort) {
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j] = valueToSort;
    }
}


public static void printArray(int[] B) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(B));
}

public static void populateArray(int[] B) {
    for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
        B[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
    }
}
}
```

I have performed binary search separately ,as follows:

```
enter code here
package binaryinsertionsort;

import java.util.Random;

/**
*
* @author Sriram
*/
public class Binaryinsertionsort {

public static void sort(int a[],int n){
    for (int i=0;i<n;++i){
        int cnt;
        int temp=a[i];
        int left=0;
        int right=i;
        while (left<right){
            int middle=(left+right)/2;
            if (temp>=a[middle])
                left=middle+1;
            else
                right=middle;
        }
        for (int j=i;j>left;--j){
            swap(a,j-1,j);
        }
      }
    }

     public static void main(String[] args){
     int a[]=new int[]{10,5,3,696,466,35,39,294,39,59,-21,45};
     sort(a,a.length);
     for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
     System.out.println(a[i]);
     }
   }
     public static void swap(int a[],int i,int j){
     int k=a[i];
     a[i]=a[j];
     a[j]=k;
   }    
 }
```

Comment: To much code, where are you having the problem?

Comment: Thanks for replying , I just posted everything so that there wont be confusion ..I am able to do binary search separately ,my question is how can i perform binary search in insertion sorting technique !!

Comment: Where is your code for searching ? How you integrate it with this one ?

Answer (score 0):

Binary search can be used to find the index where the current integer is to be inserted in the already sorted array of previous elements. This can be done using binary search which search for Key and return index value in such that **arr[i] > Key** for lowest value of i . Then you can insert in the position i using normal insertion sort method by shifting.

**Note :** The time complexity of insertion sort is still determined using the shifting method which is O(n) so binary search wouldnt change the asymptotic complexity which is O(n^2).

Comment: I wanted to have 1000 different unique values for insertion sort(1st prog).when i worked with insertion sort for that ,the repetition is there (i:e)when ran the program for 30 values i can see different integers but when try for 1000,values are repeating how can i solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question then you are asking how to use a binarySearch in implementing an insertion sort.

Using `Arrays.binarySearch` as an example, it will return the place in the index to inser a value if it can't be found. That allows a fairly trivial insertion sort:

```
int[] insertInOrder(int value, int[] destination) {
    int foundIndex = Arrays.binarySearch(destination, value);
    if (foundIndex < 0) {
         int insertIndex = -foundIndex - 1;
         int[] result = Arrays.copyOf(destination, destination.length + 1);
         for (int i = result.length - 1; i > insertIndex; i--)
             result[i] = result[i-1];
         result[insertIndex] = value;
         return result;
    } else {
        return destination;
    }
}
```

This could be made more efficient by not expanding the result each time but the basic idea is the same.